# How Do I Plot A Binomial to the Right of the Origin?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm having a seven element binomial distribution: BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], x],{x, 0, 8}] I would like to locate to any arbitrary point on the X axis. Mathematica will let me have eight columns on the X axis ranging from -0.5 on up to 7.5. How do I shift the binomial on up to say, from 5.5 to 13.5?

Comment: Joel, your code didn't copy correctly.  Would you please try again?  Also, please use the [editing tools](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to guess from your incomplete question, perhaps you want something like this:

```
Plot[
 PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], x - 6],
 {x, 5.5, 13.5},
 Frame -> True,
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mister Wizard- Your suggestion helped a lot. Is there someway I could post the Mathematica notebook to this discussion thread? Should I send you the notebook as an e-mail attachment?

Comment: @Joel Is it necessary to post an entire Notebook?  You can include a fairly long code block in your question (but please use Ctrl+K to format it).  If this is not enough room, you can open the .nb file in a text editor, copy the contents, and put that on http://pastebin.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will answer your question:

Apply the first example of the ref. page on [`BinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinomialDistribution.html) to your single distribution in place of the table, I got

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], k], {k, 0, 7}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

But this doesn't do the columns.  From looking through the "Basic Examples" section of the documentation on [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretePlot.html), I found the option [`ExtentSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtentSize.html).

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], k], {k, 0, 7}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Shifting a function can be done in the usual way, as in Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], k - 6], {k, 6, 13}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

If you would like the edges of the columns drawn, use [`EdgeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeForm.html) and the option [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html).

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.5], k - 6], {k, 6, 13}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ExtentSize -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[ColorData[1][1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]